# Is this question even remotely applicable here?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope

I was just looking around and I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839944/after-effects-duplicate-and-array-random-objects-layers

I see it has one up-vote, and the [after-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/after-effects) tag has over one-hundred questions in it. But this seems totally off-topic on this site. Am I misreading the question, misunderstanding Stack Overflow, or am I right and it's totally off-topic?

Comment: If After Effects can be scripted (it most probably can be), then questions about *that aspect* are on-topic. That specific question is not, however.

Comment: After Effects can be scripted, which makes this particular question "too broad".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only questions about specific programming problems, as well as the tools for programming tasks are on topic.

After Effects has a plugin system (according to the [after-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/after-effects) [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/after-effects/info)), so questions about *coding plugins* would be on-topic. If After Effects can be scripted, asking questions about coding in the scripting language would also be on-topic.

However, a question on using the software *itself* (so how to achieve a certain animation effect), are not on topic.

As such, a moderator has already put that question on hold.